# Why does composer removes my dependencies on deploy?

Tags: php, git, deployment, composer-php

I'm having an issue with *composer*.
I'm working with *git* in a local environment. I'm the only one developer.

When I need some more dependencies (or need to change some versions), I edit the *composer.json* and run `composer install` locally.

Everything's fine.

Then, when everything works locally, I commit my changes (including *composer.json* and *composer.lock*) and push to my production server.

A *post-receive* script updates the sources and runs a `composer install` on the remote server.

**What is expected :**

- Composer should install the new dependencies according to the *composer.lock* file.
- I should be happy.

**What happens :**

- Composer is angry :

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
>   composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to
>   update them.

- Composer **removes all dependencies**.
- My **production is broken**.
- I have a heart attack
- I have to log in to my server via ssh and run a `composer update` to make things work fine, but I know that a `composer update` is not recommended on a production server.

Here's the output of the *post-receive* composer's section :

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
  - Removing guzzle/guzzle (v3.9.3)
  - Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.7.1)
  - Removing geoip/geoip (v1.15)
  - Removing pimple/pimple (v3.0.0)
  - Removing cocur/slugify (1.1.x-dev)
  - Removing bentools/url (0.2)
  - Removing bentools/simplexmlextended (1.2.0)
Generating autoload files
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 5):

This warning

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json, you may be getting outdated dependencies, run update to update them.

occurs when the *md5sum* of your `composer.json` differs from the one stored in the `composer.lock`:

```json
{
    "hash": "b15ed9405e8547867f74973ce8add172",
    "packages": [ ... ]
}
```

Make sure your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are identically with your local ones (compare their *md5sums*). I suspect that something in your deploy chain is not updating them correctly.

Make sure you added your dependencies locally with the `require` command:

```
composer require new/package ~2.5
```

or if `composer.json` was edited manually at least run

```
composer update new/package
```

after that for every additionally added package to ensure that it is added to your `composer.lock` properly.

**Another approach:**
run `composer update --lock` in production. This will update the hash in your lock file but won't upgrade your vendors.

Then run `composer install` to install the vendors from your `comoser.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

> When I need some more dependencies (or need to change some versions), I edit the composer.json and run composer install locally.

That's wrong. You can edit `composer.json` and then must run `composer update`, or you let Composer do the internal editing of the json file and just run `composer require new/package` (optionally with a version).

Either way, you should end up with a changed `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file, commit BOTH into your repository, and the expected outcome is that the lock file will contain all packages in the correct versions, which should be installed in production with a regular `composer install` run.

Note that your workflow is still very dangerous. If you push, and Github is down - how would you get the ZIPs to install?

Comment: OK, I'll do it this way then. For the case github is down, what is your advice ?

Comment: Neither Git nor Composer are deployment tools. They get used as such a lot, but that doesn't mean it's the best solution. In general, you'd put together a ZIP or TGZ containing all code needed for the production update (including the code in Git as well as everything from Composer), move it to the production machine, unpack it, (test it in a hidden place - optional), and then switch to it instantly. There are tools for this - Capistrano is one of them. To avoid Github downtimes and faster access, use Satis to create a local copy of dependencies you use. Details would warrant a new question.